# Как в Spring 5 задать язык по умолчанию?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, i18n

В моем приложении я использую три языка:
- Английски
- Русский
- Эстонский (к примеру)

Смена языка происходит посредством переходи на ссылку, которая оканчивается: `******/?lang=en`, `******/?lang=ee`, `******/?lang=ru`.

При выборе другого языка или написание рандомной переменной, моя страница переводится на "язык по умолчанию" (который я настроил в `WebMvcConfig.java`), однако переменная (в thymeleaf) `${#locale.language}` остается такой, какой был указан в URL, то есть при написании в URL `..../?lang=random`, в -аттрибуте будет так: `<html ... lang="random">`.

Вопрос: Как сделать так, что если пользователь вводит рандомное значение переменной `lang` в URL, моя программа присваивала бы этой переменной язык по умолчанию (в моем случае - `ru`)?

**WebMvcConfig.java:**

```java
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:local/messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver resolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ru"));
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeInterceptor;
    }


    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeInterceptor());
    }

}
```

main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:lang="${#locale.language}">
```

[image: Скриншот]

***Если требуется дополнительная информация - напишите об этом в комментариях.***

Comment: Может ограничить набор языков выпадающим списком? Тогда пользователь просто не сможет ввести рандомное значение.

Comment: @Z.John так и реализовано, НО в URL строке он может написать ‘?lang=fr’ и это все испортит) я хочу избежать данных недочетов в программе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ прост:

Создаем отдельный файл. Допустим `LanguageHandler.java`. В нем пишем следующее:

```java
public class LanguageHandler extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        SessionLocaleResolver sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        List<String> languages = new ArrayList<>(); //Это нам нужно для проверки языков
        languages.add("ee");
        languages.add("en");
        languages.add("ru");

        //Если указанного языка нет в списке, то, допустим, ставим по дефолта русский
        if(!languages.contains(request.getParameter("lang")) && request.getParameter("lang") != null){
                sessionLocaleResolver.setLocale(request, response, new Locale("ru"));
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

В вашем конфигураторе надо добавить следующую строчку:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    /*
    Некоторый код
    */

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        //Некоторый код

        registry.addInterceptor(new LanguageHandler());
    }

}
```

И теперь в HTML-файле все будет работать исправно.

Вот пример HTML-кода для Thymeleaf:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:lang="${#locale.language}"
>
```

Comment: Да, ровно это я и имел ввиду, все реализовано отлично.

Answer (score 1):

Реализуйте свой собственный перехвадчик на базе LocaleChangeInterceptor или HandlerInterceptorAdapter. Добавьте его вместо вашего дефолтного LocaleChangeInterceptor.

Вам потребуется переписать метод preHandle как то так:

```
@Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        sessionLocaleResolver.setLocale(request, response, Locale.ENGLISH); // здесь будет ваша логика, для примера происходит замена на English при любом значений параметра
        return true;
    }
```

Как видно из примера, нужную вам логику (замену языка и работу с переменной) вы можете указать переписав метод preHandle.

Comment: да, это похоже то, что надо. Сейчас протестирую